# Is my homemade chandelier design safe and does it meet code?

Tags: wiring

I have built a hanging bulb chandelier. It has 13 bulbs total (7) 25W LED and (6) 60W standard filament bulbs. They go into 2 wire sockets with no ground. I used 18/2 cloth jacketed wire and ran them into a metal electrical box which is fastened to the top of the fixture. I connected all the black wire using 5 port Wago lever nuts and the same with the red wire. I then connected one of the black wires and one of the red wires to the wires coming out of the ceiling which were 14/2 Wground via wago lever nut. I attached the ground wire to the box which is attached to the fixture. I have created a very crude diagram. Can anyone take a look and let me know if this looks alright and is up to code? Thank you very much. [image: crude diagram]
[image: The chandelier is solid Walnut. Thank you in advance for your help...]

Thank you very much for looking into my question.

Comment: alright electrically? more than. Up to code? no clue.

Comment: I don't see a ground on this anywhere. The NEC doesn't really cover the manufacturing of light fixtures. There are other regulating authorities that do that. Primarily UL, and I know it's not UL approved.

Comment: There's really no such thing as "braided" wire, FYI.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician  Can you tell me why it's not UL approved and what I need to do to make it that way?

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician If I were to take the ground from the ceiling and attach it to the metal box on the fixture, would that be sufficient?

Comment: It is not UL approved, for the simple fact that you have not sent it to Underwriters Laboratory for testing and approval.

Comment: Are you looking to sell these or use it in your house? If it's the later then maybe the better question is "Is this Fixture Safe?"

Comment: @PlatinumGoose  Either way, I would not sell it or put it in someone's house if it were not safe. Hence the original question. Do you see Danny safety issues with it? If so please point it out, I do not want to cause any damage.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose  I'm not being smart, I'm honestly asking.

Comment: I didn't take your response as you being smart. You asked if it was up to code and if it was safe. I was just asking because depending what you're looking to accomplish will get you different answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because. Not a listed product and OP is looking for a its ok to install.

Comment: @ed beal Please God tell me what you are talking about.

Comment: You seam to be asking for approval for a non listed product.  The only way I know of to get approval from the local inspector

Comment: So Ed, are you saying that I should contact my local inspector?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the pertinent National Code Articles:

> **410.6 Listing Required.**  All luminaires, lampholders, and retrofit kits shall be listed

And

> **Article 100 Definitions.** Listed.  Equipment, materials, or services included in a list published by an organization that is acceptable to the authority having jurisdiction and concerned with evaluation of products or services, that maintains periodic inspection of production of listed equipment or materials or periodic evaluation of services, and whose listing states that either the equipment, material, or service meets appropriate designated standards or has been tested and found suitable for a specified purpose.

That being the case, I was at a commercial building in Austin, Texas that had almost the same design but with old time lamps and copper plumbing pipe. Definitely NOT a commercial fixture. However, the inspector approved it and that will override the listing requirement.

So, if your local Electrical Inspector says it's good then you are good.

Cool design. Good Luck!